# NSDateFormatter return nil for dateFromString when using AM or PM

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsdateformatter

So maybe someone knows this, since I can't seem to find any info on it. For iOS 8.0.4, using this causes dateFromString to return nil.

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [NSDateFormatter new];
[df setDateFormat:@"h:mma"];
NSDate *defaultDate = [df dateFromString:@"12:00PM"];
```

This works fine when I build it for my other device which is on iOS 8.1.x. I've also tried variations of "h:mm aa" or "h:mm a" and adjusting the dateFromString parameter, but it still returns nil. Is this not possible?

Comment: Please look up the many, many questions and answers on this site in relation to this - you need to specify the locale for the dateformatter to get it to work as you want, otherwise it takes the user's preference; ignoring the developer's choice

Comment: Is the device causing the problem set to 24-hour time or 12-hour time?

Comment: @Petesh: Ya, if I knew I had to look at "locale", sure. This was new to me so I asked. Oops, my bad. I guess I should already "know" it. I'll try to know all the things first before posting a "question" on a question and answer site.

Comment: @rmaddy, thank you. That was it.

Comment: @rmaddy: So I know, can the specific question that this is a duplicate of be linked here so it will help others?

Comment: It is. See the very top of your question.

Comment: Okay, thats good. Probably a refresh issue when I didnt see it. In any case, I didn't know the device hour format setting would cause that so my searches had nothing to do with that setting and more just straight about dateFromString. Thanks again. I really need to stop asking here...

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't actually a version issue. The other device I was testing on was set to 24-hour format and that caused the nil return. So I added this line:

```
[df setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
```